# ActiveResource can't validate confirmation of attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activeresource

I have this resource:

```
require 'active_resource'

class User < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v2'
  self.include_format_in_path = false

  schema do
    attribute :id,                 :integer
    attribute :name,               :string
    attribute :password,           :string
    attribute :email,              :string
  end

  validates :email, confirmation: true
  # alternatively, tried with:
  # validates_confirmation_of :email
end
```

When I call:

```
user = User.new(
  name: 'My name',
  email: 'an@email.com',
  email_confirmation: 'another@email.com',
  password: 'some_password'
)
```

and then `user.errors`, I would expect it to return an error about the `email_confirmation` not matching `email`. However, it doesn't. `user.valid?` always returns `true`.

Moreover, `user.email` returns `'an@email.com'`, but `user.email_confirmation` returns `nil`.

I tested validating the password too, and looks like any `user.xxx_confirmation` will return `nil`.

How are we supposed to validate confirmations on ActiveResource?

Comment: email_confirmation shouldn't be a real attribute... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation

Comment: I thought so, but I tried removing it from `schema`, it still does not work :/

Comment: @BradWerth just to make it clear, it's an `ActiveResource`, not an `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: what if you add an attr_accessor, or maybe presence validation?

Comment: @BradWerth is correct here - you should remove the `email_confirmation` attribute from the "schema". `validates_confirmation_of` creates a setter for the `x_confirmation` attribute. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_confirmation_of

Comment: @max agreed. I also tried validating using `validates_confirmation_of :email`, but it doesn't work either. `user.valid?` will return `true`, and `user.errors` won't return any errors.

Comment: I'm guessing reason the validation is not running is because `email_confirmation` is nil like the documentation states. The question is really why is it nil? Also bear in mind that the `errors` object is empty until you call `.valid?` on the model which causes the validations to be run.

Comment: Perfect, understood. However, it still does not validate :/